# How can I get the email field value from a webform and use the rules module to send mail on submit event?

Tags: webforms

How can I get the value of the email field value in a webform and apply it in

rule > action > send email > to address

I have tried using a token but could not get the value.

Answer (score 8):

If you have an email field on the webform then that field will be available to you at webform/emails in the selector alongside the radio button = Component Value

That then becomes the 'to' field unless you then overwrite it.

You will also find 'select' type fields in that selector as you can then set email address for each of the options in the email settings directly.

You would use this if for example you had a field on the form for 'country' and needed to send the submission to different contacts based on which country was chosen.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

i got the vale from rule data replacement in the data section which has [data:data] contains all data of webform content and through [data:"component_key_value"-value] we will get the value of the component,the double quotes should not present while replacing component key value